# Is it possible to print web content on thermal printer?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Do you think it's possible to print a web content on a thermal print ? And is it possible to print it without pressing a button ?

I refresh my page every 30s and if there is a new order it displays on the screen and I would like the print prints directly without asking anything. I created a new page with the information to print and I would like to print this page.

Edit : is there a script that permits to print whatever content we want without passing by an interface ?

Comment: you can't force to print something without user interaction or approval. If you're the end user, maybe you can hack it with some browser plugin or extension

Comment: But is it possible to print  a web content on a thermal print ?

Comment: depends on your printer, but it should be possible

Comment: it's a printer to print order form

Comment: there's a feature in chrome " --kiosk-printing", if this is only for your use, you can enable it in your browser. that way it would send it silently to your default printer. ONLY FOR YOUR USE, it's impossible to force print directly from a webpage

Comment: this is deffinitly possible. what I worked on in my previous companies was generating and printing labels on thermal companies. but then i guess the question is what do you want ot print. About the printing without user interaction, I never had to do it but I only guess using some php would make it and I would start thinking using a foreach loop for each new result send form to print. But still there should be a printer to select etc and I m not sure web languages can pass over it. hope it will lead you somewhere

Comment: I just have to put this kind ([thermal print](http://www.ldlc.com/informatique/peripherique-pc/imprimante-thermique/c4640/)) of printer by default and it will work ?

Comment: The use case you're describing (polling a queue and dispatching events to a device) isn't suitable for a browser, even if you can make it work. Consider a server-side solution.

Comment: There is an add-on for Firefox, maybe it help https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/seamless-print/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use the options `--kiosk-printing --kiosk --disable-background-timer-throttling` on chrome and launch printing with `window.print()` in javascript.

How to activate the options mentioned above in Google Chrome: https://www.shoptill-e.com/support/48

Answer (score 0):

it is possible if you use a mobile app. See my below Android app which prints any content on bluetooth thermal printer from a website.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mate.bluetoothprint&hl=en_IN

I have used manual method in my app but you can make everything automated with your custom app. e.g. once an order is generated on your website, it will trigger firebase event and call your android / ios app which is connected to thermal printer and it will print automatically